# Detect high-quality information from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-analysis

I'm very interested in what methods are used to extract high-quality information from Stack Overflow. For example, a user researches a topic and Stack Overflow returns thousends of results. Is there is a method on SO to return the answer from the answerer with the highest repution or the question that get many upvotes.

Do we have an online tool to analyse information from Stack Overflow?

Comment: Huh? Maybe elaborate some more, please...

Comment: First you must understand how to write high-quality content.

Comment: @Garden:for example a user search about a topic and stackoverflow returns thousends of results .But I want to know,if there is a methode in stckovf to return the answer ,which the answerer have high repution or the question get many positive points from other users.

Comment: "stckovf"? Seriously?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/faq

Comment: Why do you want to do this:  To read the content?  To copy the content to a website you own?  To find the answer to a question with a search query that returns lots of results?

Comment: @kevin: I'm a student and I have a seminar about detect high-quality information in social web and I  wanted only to know how can man exctract high quality information in STACKOVERFLOW as popular social web.but it seems my post leads to a misunderstand(may be because of my bad English)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a search facility in the top right of each site. [Reading the documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) you will discover that you can search for user related content `user:147520` subject related content using [tag] notation e.g. [c++] would return results from within [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). You can use `votes:n` to filter posts that have n or more votes so [[c++] votes:16](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20votes:200) would return very highly up voted posts from [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ...